# Jetty 9 embedded SSL takes 12 minutes to start

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I have a Spring application running on top of Jetty. We have recently upgraded the Jetty version thats being used from 6.x up to the newest stable version 9.4.14

All seemed to be set up and working well until we came to running the build version of the application. When booting it takes Jetty 12 minutes to start the Server!

My log:

```
2019-02-08 14:54:15,917 INFO [ContextHandler] Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1f554b06{RTD2,/web,file:///data/XXX/war/,AVAILABLE}{/data/XXX/war}
2019-02-08 14:54:16,123 INFO [SslContextFactory] x509=X509@33beb1(1,h=[XXX.co.uk],w=[XXX.co.uk]) for SslContextFactory@480f6625[provider=null,keyStore=file:///data/XX/config/keystore2,trustStore=file:///etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts]
2019-02-08 15:07:08,063 WARN [config] No Client EndPointIdentificationAlgorithm configured for SslContextFactory@480f6625[provider=null,keyStore=file:///data/XX/config/keystore2,trustStore=file:///etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts]
2019-02-08 15:07:08,101 INFO [AbstractConnector] Started ServerConnector@124e2ad9{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:443}
2019-02-08 15:07:08,101 INFO [Server] Started @820820ms
```

My starting class:

```
public class RunJetty {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length < 4) {
            System.out.println("Insufficient arguments supplied");
            usage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {

            int port = getPort(args[0]);
            File configLocation = getContextLocation(args[1]);
            String contextPath = getContextPath(args[2]);
            String scheme = args[3];
            String resourceBase = args(args, 4, "html");

            Server server = new Server();

            ServerConnector sslConnector = null;
            boolean https = scheme.equals("https");
            boolean http = scheme.equals("http");
            boolean both = scheme.equals("both");
            int sslPort = -1;
            if (https || both) {

                HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
                httpConfig.setSendServerVersion( false );
                httpConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
                HttpConnectionFactory httpFactory = new HttpConnectionFactory( httpConfig );

                SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
                sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(System.getProperty("jetty.ssl.keystore"));
                sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(System.getProperty("jetty.ssl.keystore.password"));
                sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(System.getProperty("jetty.ssl.key.password"));
                sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath(System.getProperty("jetty.ssl.truststore"));
                sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword(System.getProperty("jetty.ssl.truststore.password"));

                SslConnectionFactory sslFactory =  new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString());

                sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,sslFactory,httpFactory);

                sslPort = https ? port : Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("ssl.port"));
                sslConnector.setPort(sslPort);

            }

            ServerConnector connector = null;

            if (http || both) {

                HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
                httpConfig.setSendServerVersion( false );
                if (both) {
                    httpConfig.setSecurePort(sslPort);
                }
                HttpConnectionFactory httpFactory = new HttpConnectionFactory( httpConfig );

                connector = new ServerConnector( server,httpFactory );
                connector.setPort(port);
            }

            Connector[] connectors = null;

            if (both) {
                connectors = new Connector[] { connector, sslConnector };
            } else if (http) {
                connectors = new Connector[] { connector };
            } else if (https) {
                connectors = new Connector[] { sslConnector };
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid scheme. Must be 'http', 'https' or 'both'");
            }

            server.setConnectors(connectors);

            HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
            ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
            resourceHandler.setResourceBase(resourceBase);

            ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();

            WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext(configLocation.getAbsolutePath(), contextPath);

            contexts.addHandler(webAppContext);

            RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
            handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contexts, resourceHandler, new DefaultHandler(), requestLogHandler });
            server.setHandler(handlers);

            server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

            try {
                server.start();
                server.join();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            usage();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    static String args(String[] args, int index, String defaultValue) {
        if (args.length < index+1) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return args[index];
    }

    static String getContextPath(String arg) {
        if (!arg.startsWith("/")) {
            arg = "/" + arg;
        }
        return arg;
    }

    static File getContextLocation(String arg) {
        File file = new File(arg);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid context directory: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return file;
    }

    static int getPort(String arg) {
        int port = 8080;
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(arg);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid port: " + arg);
        }
        return port;
    }


    private static void usage() {
        System.out.println(RunJetty.class.getName() + " [port] [context directory] [path] [http|https|both]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable debug logging and see how long each of your contexts actually takes to load / start / deploy. There will be timing for each step produced in the debug logs output.

Comment: The most common time consuming deployment step is dealing with `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar!/META-INF/resources` content, especially of various javascript bootstrap libraries out there (some are as large as 10,000 files in a 390MB jar file!).  Any bytecode scanning step (servlet and spring) will take a long time going through those kinds of jars.